# Encrypt/Decrypt strings to a database in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: encryption, cryptography, .net-core

in the process of researching Cryptography possibilities in .NET Core 2.0.  I've noticed a few simple examples using IDataProtectionProvider, but I need more.  This only secures things for days, and I need to secure stuff in a database for a longer time, AND on a per-user basis.

I've experimented with the RSA.Create() class, but it doesn't seem to have any functionality for me to specify a specific key to use.

Is this the right way?  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean ... "This only secures things for days" ?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 - IDataProtectionProvider apparently manages its own keys and cycles them every X amount of days so if you want to keep something encrypted long term its best to use a different encryption scheme.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of work, I got this figured out.  I decided to use Aes.Create() to do AES encryption.  This API allows you to have a simple byte[] key.

Make sure you remember to GenerateIV() to get a new Initialization Vector every time, and store that info somewhere with encrypted data.  A new IV every time makes it much more cryptographically strong.